# html can't get photo with a correct address return 404

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, http-status-code-404

So I'm using spring and tomcat and their exist a photo in my /opt/webapps/images/xxxx.jpeg and in my html page i want to get the photo by
 `<img src="/opt/webapps/images/xxxx.jpeg" id="imgProfile" style="width: 150px; height: 150px" class="img-thumbnail" />` which we agreed is corrected but it always return a 404.

so why?

Comment: `404` says it's not correct, regardless of what "whoever" agreed is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml configuration add:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/opt/webapps/images/**" />
```

In your jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
        <link href="<c:url value="/resources/xxxx.jpeg" />" >
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you add <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> in your .jsp file, your file must be a .jsp